# Allow VirtualBox machine to access IIS site on host machine

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running a virtual machine using VirtualBox and I'd like the virtual machine to able to access a site that is hosted in IIS on the host machine (my computer).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your VM networking capabilities, connecting to the same network as the host machine will allow the two to communicate / allow you to browse the site from the VM.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html